# @Assisted Guice parameter injection depending on controller

Tags: scala, playframework, guice

Suppose I have a service Service which needs to be injected in two Play Framework Controllers and depending on a controller, a parameter of the service (param1) should contain one or the other constant value. My first guess is the @Assisted route, but installing factory through a Module seems to diverge from what I'm trying to achieve.

```
class Controller1 @Inject()(service: Service) extends Controller...
class Controller2 @Inject()(service: Service) extends Controller...
class Service @Inject()(@Assisted param1: String, param2: Int...)
```

Any clue on this or suggestion on a different approach?

Comment: Pass the `param1` and `param2` as method paramters?

Comment: See "robot legs" problem, [here](https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/FrequentlyAskedQuestions).

Comment: Why not two [@Named](https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/BindingAnnotations#named) instances of service?